# Searching for a string in a dictionary in an array swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

This example involves a todo app context, I have the following code to add a todo to the list:

```
let userDefaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var itemList:NSMutableArray = userDefaults.objectForKey("itemList") as NSMutableArray
let dataSet:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
dataSet.setObject(titleTextField.text, forKey: "itemTitle")               
dataSet.setObject(notesTextField.text, forKey: "itemNotes")

if ((itemList) != nil) {
      let newList:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray(
      for dict:AnyObject in itemList{
           newList.addObject(dict as! NSDictionary)
      }
      userDefaults.removeObjectForKey("itemList")
      newList.addObject(dataSet)
      userDefaults.setObject(newList, forKey: "itemList")
}
else{
      userDefaults.removeObjectForKey("itemList")
      itemList = NSMutableArray(
      itemList.addObject(dataSet)
      userDefaults.setObject(itemList, forKey: "itemList")
}

userDefaults.synchronize()
self.navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

How would I search in the dictionary/array to look for multiple `itemTitle` so that if the user creates the title twice it will then send them an error message that informs them they've created the title twice and it must be changed before they add the new todo?

Comment: two suggestions: Todo's are easily represented with a database graph and thus CoreData is a much better/easier solution. Replace all `!` in your code with appropriate downcasts or optional bindings.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that using CoreData is easier, but I'd still like to know the answer without having to use CoreData, thanks

Comment: Update your code in the question so it has no more problematic force-unwraps/downcasts. Else there is little point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres what I did to solve this:

In the button that saved the to do list I...

```
let userDefaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let itemList:NSMutableArray? = userDefaults.objectForKey("itemList") as? NSMutableArray
if (itemList?.count > 0) {
        array1 = (itemList?.valueForKey("itemTitle"))! as! [String]
        if (array1.count > 0) {
            for i in 0...array1.count-1 {
                if array1[i] == titleText {
                    print("title is already in the to do list")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Predicate for searching the particular key in an array in SWIFT 2

```
let myPredicate = NSPredicate(format:  "education_name contains[c]%@",passedString)
let mySearchingArray = arrayHoldingData.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(myPredicate)
```